# Check intersection of two arrays of datasets

Tags: apache-spark

I want to check the intersection of two arrays of small datasets, i do it like so :

```
 for (Dataset<Row> dataset1 : arrayOfDatasets1) {
        for (Dataset<Row> dataset2 : arrayOfDatasets2) {
            if (dataset1.intersect(dataset2).count() != 0)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Given datasets have schema, is the above method appropriate ? or should i use :

`dataset1.intersect(dataset2).  () != sparksession.emptyDataframe()`

instead to compare the datasets ?

Comment: [Try it and See!](https://tryitands.ee)

Comment: i did found that count works